# How to get Launchd to change /etc/hosts and reset DNS cache?

Tags: macos, launchd, launch-daemon

I've been trying to setup Launchd to block several websites on osX 10.11.6

The script doesn't seem to execute during the scheduled times.

What is strange is that launchd seems to execute the commands when I load the plist, but does not execute the commands during the scheduled time. The /etc/hosts is updated with the sites to block but the  websites are not blocked.

What is strange is that launchd seems to execute the commands when I load the plist, but does not execute the commands during the scheduled time.

Some googling suggested that I might need to reset the DNS cache:

```
sudo dscacheutil -flushcache;sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder
```

When I run that from the command line I can still access the sites that should be blocked.  I don't know how to add this to the launchd plist program arguments either if it were to work.

$ cat /Library/LaunchDaemons/local.hosts.blockingAM.plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">  
<plist version="1.0">  
<dict>  
    <key>Label</key>  
    <string>local.hosts.blockingAM</string>  
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>  
    <array>  
        <string>cp</string>  
        <string>/etc/hosts_BLOCKED_sites.txt</string>  
        <string>/etc/hosts</string>  
    </array>  
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>  
    <true/>  
    <key>StartCalendarInterval</key>  
    <array>  
        <dict>  
            <key>Hour</key>  
            <integer>8</integer>  
            <key>Minute</key>  
            <integer>15</integer>  
            <key>Weekday</key>  
            <integer>1</integer>  
        </dict>  
        <dict>  
            <key>Hour</key>  
            <integer>8</integer>  
            <key>Minute</key>  
            <integer>15</integer>  
            <key>Weekday</key>  
            <integer>2</integer>  
        </dict>  
        <dict>  
            <key>Hour</key>  
            <integer>9</integer>  
            <key>Minute</key>  
            <integer>35</integer>  
            <key>Weekday</key>  
            <integer>3</integer>  
        </dict>  
        <dict>  
            <key>Hour</key>  
            <integer>8</integer>  
            <key>Minute</key>  
            <integer>15</integer>  
            <key>Weekday</key>  
            <integer>4</integer>  
        </dict>  
        <dict>  
            <key>Hour</key>  
            <integer>8</integer>  
            <key>Minute</key>  
            <integer>15</integer>  
            <key>Weekday</key>  
            <integer>5</integer>  
        </dict>  
    </array>  

    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>  
    <string>/tmp/local.hosts.blocking.err</string>                                                           
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>   
    <string>/tmp/local.hosts.blocking.out</string>    
    </dict>  
    </plist>
```

Here are the permissions:
$ ls -la  /Library/LaunchDaemons/local.hosts.blockingAM.plist

```
-rw-r--r--@ 1 root  wheel  1474 Sep  8 09:33 /Library/LaunchDaemons/local.hosts.blockingAM.plist
```

I load up the plist with:

```
$ sudo launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/local.hosts.blockingAM.plist
```

There are no errors recorded:
$ cat /tmp/local.hosts.blocking.err

Here is the file containing blocked sites:
$ cat /etc/hosts_BLOCKED_sites.txt

```
##  
# Host Database  
#  
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface  
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.  
##  
127.0.0.1   localhost  
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost  
::1             localhost   


# Blocked sites redirected to 0.0.0.0  
0.0.0.0 reddit.com www.reddit.com  
0.0.0.0 facebook.com www.facebook.com
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which OSX version?

Comment: 10.11.6 current version